# client sending two messagese to servlet successivley using url object

Tags: url, servlets, stream

My servlet on receiving first request from client:

```
//1.
ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(req.getInputStream());
String r=(String) in.readObject();
in.close();

ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());
writer.writeObject(pk);
writer.close();

//ON receiving second request:
//2.
ObjectInputStream in1=new ObjectInputStream(req.getInputStream());
String s=(String) in1.readObject();
in1.close();

OutputStreamWriter writer1 = new OutputStreamWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
writer1.write(reverseStr);
writer1.close();
```

But on both request only 1. is getting executed. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question without actually studying servlets. A servlet's method(doPost(),doGet()  etc) are each called time a request is made to the servlet. Only the init() method is initialized or executed only once.
So each time a call is made to the above servlet, it starts executing from #line1.